# How to publish Windows Store App with enterpriseAuthentication and sharedUserCertificates

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am a developer who is new to Windows Store development.
I wrote one Windows Store App and tried to upload it, yet I encounter some errors after submit the appxupload file.
The error messages are shown as below:
[image]

I have no idea how to make my developer account authorized to publish apps with the capability it mentioned. Is there a different set of capability for different developer account for Windows Store Application?

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Apps that use these capabilities must be submitted through a company account (not an individual account), and are also reserved for very specific scenarios and require written justifications.